# C variables in struct have same address each other

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

define code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int count_t;

typedef struct ptid_t {
    short           index;    
    short           ioffset;   
    unsigned char           type;      
    unsigned char           networkType;
} ptid_t;

typedef union ptid_lst {
    count_t count; 
    ptid_t  item[1];
} plist_t;
```

main code :

```
int main(void) {

    plist_t test;

    memset(&test, 0x0, sizeof(plist_t));

    test.count = 0xABCDABCD;

    printf("%x\n", test.count);
    printf("%x\n", test.item[0].index);
    printf("%x\n", test.item[0].ioffset);

    return 0;
}
```

console output :

```
abcdabcd
ffffabcd
ffffabcd
```

I just trying to change struct first value 'count' but other variables are changed. 
The change value is 'count' in plist_t. but, why index and ioffset variables are changed both? 
Because of this situation, I try to get the variable's address and result :

```
0x80479f4
0x80479f4
0x80479f6
```

The 'count' variable and item[0] struct has same address. why occured this situation? 
In oppsite case are same too.

```
int main(void) {

    plist_t test;

    memset(&test, 0x0, sizeof(plist_t));

    test.item[0].index = 0xabcd;
    test.item[0].ioffset = 0xabc0;

    printf("%x\n", test.count);
    printf("%x\n", test.item[0].index);
    printf("%x\n", test.item[0].ioffset);

    return 0;
}


console output:
abc0abcd
ffffabcd
ffffabc0
```

Comment: Do you understand what a `union` is in C? Your question should be "C variables in union have same address". Because you are really comparing fields in a union not in a struct.

Comment: I think you want a `struct` instead of a `union`. In a union, either the `count` or the `item` (or neither) is valid at any point in time, making it safe for their representations to be overlaid in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `plist_t` isn't a struct, it's a union

In C, each member of a union starts at the same memory address.

If you want to change them independently, simply convert `plist_t` into a struct instead:

```
typedef struct ptid_lst {
    count_t count; 
    ptid_t  item[1];
} plist_t;
```